# Сервер gin возвращает 404 ошибку в браузере

Tags: golang, rest

Данный код не работает в браузере, но работает через curl.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type News struct {
    ID    string `json:"id"`
    Title string `json:"title"`
}

var result = []News{{ID: "0", Title: "sdfsdfsdf"}}

func getAlbums(c *gin.Context) {
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, result)
}

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.GET("/result", getAlbums)

    router.Run("localhost:8080")

}
```

Comment: Проверьте URL в браузере. У меня `http://localhost:8080/result` возвращает `[
    {
        "id": "0",
        "title": "sdfsdfsdf"
    }
]`

Comment: @PakUula, о чем я и написал, в браузере у 404 ошибка, страница не найдена

Comment: @PakUula изначально все работало , но что-то пошло не так

Comment: @PakUula, стоп , ты прав , не верно url указал в строке